# JSON data coming from a successful Flask POST request not getting passed to AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, flask

Below is my flask view:

```
import db_connect_test
from db_connect_test import Viz_Connector
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash,json,jsonify
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def select_ID():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ID=request.form['input_ID']
        Node_type = request.form['Node_Type']
        while True:
            try:
                data = Viz_Connector(ID,Node_type).get_data()
                return  render_template('dropdown.html',data=jsonify(data))
                break
            except IndexError:
                return "Wrong ID"


    return render_template('dropdown.html')
```

Below is my jquery/ajax. I am using it because I have a drop down in my HTML:

All the jquery code is saved in a file called "final.js" and is referenced in the HTML below.

```
 $('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
  var input_ID = $("#input_ID").val();
  var Node_Type = $("#Node_Type").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/",
    dataType: 'json',

    data: {
      input_ID: input_ID,
      Node_Type: Node_Type,
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Below is the HTML for input ID and ID_type:

```
        <form action="{{url_for('select_ID')}}" method="POST">
      <label for="input_ID">ID</label>
      <input id="input_ID" type="text" />


      <label for="Node_Type">Node_Type</label>
      <select id="Node_Type">
     <option value=Customer>Customer</option>
    <option value=Phone>Phone</option>
    <option value=ID_Card>ID_Card</option>
  </select>


  <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
  <script src="{{url_for('static',filename='final.js')}}"></script>

</form>
```

A drop down is being used for ID_Type and has 3 possible values

```
   "Customer","Phone" and "ID_Card".
```

"ID" is a text field and has values

```
 "C1","C2","C3","C4","C5","C6" for "Customer" 
 "ID1", "ID2" ,"ID3","ID4" for ID_Card 
  "P1" ,"P2" for phone.
```

The back end server is a neo4j database server.

On entering

```
   "C1" as ID and ID_type as "Customer"
```

below data was generated:

On running the flask view I get a successful POST: 200. But the

```
  console.log(data) seems to display the entire HTML page and **NOT** the data from the server.
```

Comment: What values have `ID` and `Node_Type` on server-side when you click button ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai added more details that you asked for in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , the issue was that I was also returning render template('dropdown.html').

Modified the flask code as below:

```
 import db_connect_test
from db_connect_test import Viz_Connector
from flask import Flask, request, session, redirect, url_for, render_template, flash,json,jsonify
import os
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def select_ID():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ID=request.form['input_ID']
        Node_type = request.form['Node_Type']
        while True:
            try:
                data = Viz_Connector(ID,Node_type).get_data()
                return  json.dumps(data)//no rendering of template

                break
            except IndexError:
                return "Wrong ID"


return render_template('dropdown.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Flask's `jsonify()` function to pass data:

```
return jsonify(data=data)
```

Documentation: [AJAX with jQuery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/jquery/).

Edit you $.ajax method:

```
...
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
...
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. Even though the documentation says it.

Comment: It seems that your ajax method was wrong, try to edit it (see answer).

Comment: so now console.log(data) displays the entire HTML page and not the server data.